# Unable to Resolve Merge Conflicts in Bitbucket

Tags: merge, bitbucket, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

While merging my branch code with master, I was having merge conflicts and most of them got resolved but I'm unable to resolve merge conflicts on few files as I'm unable to accept the changes or stage them.

In Sourcetree, whenever I try to resolve the conflicts using 'theirs', I get the error - 'Cannot update one or more files, please check that no other application is locking your files' whereas, when I try to resolve conflicts using 'mine', it does not show this error and neither does it do anything and the merge conflict still remains. Not really sure as to why I'm not able to merge the files.

While trying to merge each file manually from the editor, there is no error or conflicts are displayed but still I'm unable to stage that particular file. In git output it shows that no changes are present to be merged but this file always is being displayed in the Merge Changes part with conflicts.

Comment: I'm seeing more than one, probably unrelated, problem here.  Regarding the merge conflicts, just open up those files in an editor and manually do the merge.  If that still fails, then edit your question and tell us what the exact problem is.

Comment: While trying to merge each file manually from the visual studio code editor, there is no error or conflict displayed but still I'm unable to stage that particular file. In git output it shows that no changes are present to be merged but this file always is being displayed in the Merge Changes part with conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Could-not-update-one-or-more-files/qaq-p/602194), check if this is the case when the conflict invove deleting the file:

> For me it seems like this happened with the "theirs" change being a delete, so "resolving using theirs" should delete the file.
> I worked around it by marking the files as resolved then deleting them manually.

You see also a similar scenario in [SRCTREEWIN-2366](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-2366?focusedCommentId=1631899&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1631899):

> I think this error, at least for me, was a red herring. This happened to me and I tracked it back to a file that I had removed on one branch and changed on the other.
>
> Source tree showed me this error when I tried to resolve with mine.
> But, when I tried to resolve from the command line by checking out my version, git gave me an error that at 'ours' the file didn't exist.
> I resolved the conflict to accept mine by knowing the file had been removed.
> So, I just removed it myself then committed.